# How to remove white blank page which appears after splash screen in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on a project which is in ionic framework.When I start the app there is a splash screen of login. When I logged in , for some time there is a white Blank screen appears and then next view is get rendered. I want to remove that white blank screen. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I tried many versions of [cordova-plugin-splashscreen](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen), and I found that version 2.0.0 works perfect. Please try it, regards:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen@2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Install splashscreen

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
```

And set the following preferences in the config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a setTimeout function to programatically hide the splash screen:
Previously you need set:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

Then:

```
initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.splashScreen.hide();
  }, 3000);
});
```

}